# reroute to another action/controller in mvc4 using angular js controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am trying to anularize a legacy asp.net mvc4 application. After the web api http.put is executed inside the angular js controller, I would like the page to be directed to another asp.net mvc4 action/controller. How is it possible?

```
$scope.saveEditProfile = function () {
    $http.put("/api/ProfileWeb", $scope.profile)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.profile = response.data;
        });
```

**// need some sort of reroute instruction here to route to asp.net mvc Action = Inedex and Controller =Profile.**

```
};
```

Comment: You would not be able to use the response.data if you process to a redirect. If by redirect you mean "another view", you can use the $location service. In any other case, you should wait for the promise resolution to be sure the query has been done, and handle errors if needed. Do your redirection only after that.

Comment: At this point, I am interesetd in response.data. If the put operation is successful, I would like to execute redirect to another view

Comment: so how do I redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
  window.location ="/Profile/Index";
```

ie:

```
    $scope.saveEditProfile = function () {
            $http.put("/api/ProfileWeb", $scope.profile)
                .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.profile = response.data;    
                  window.location ="/Profile/Index";        
       }); 

  };
```